# Inequality for quadratic function and exponent

Tags: inequality

I might be a but rusty but while doing probability tasks i got stuck on some inequalities from analysis.

The task is to prove that there exists $K>0$, so that:

$$ \left|\frac{1}{1+e^{3x}} \right|^2 +1 \leq K+K|x|^2$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $e^{3x}>0$, $$ \left|\frac{1}{1+e^{3x}} \right|^2 +1 < \left(\frac{1}{1+0}\right)^2+1=2\le 2+2x^2$$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 2):

We can easily prove that the function $f(x) = \left(\frac{1}{1+e^{3x}}\right)^2+1$ is stricly decreasing in $\mathbb R$ (we can take the first derivative and we will see that it is strictly negative). Thus, we have that:
$$\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x)  =2.$$

So, picking any $K\ge 2$  will do the job.

Answer (score 2):

The LHS is less than $2$. The RHS is some parabola:
$$
g(x) = K + K \lvert x \rvert^2 = K(x^2 + 1)
$$
So you need to pick $K$ such that the parabola's minimum is not less than $2$.

The minimum of $g$ is at $x =0$ and $g(0) = K$, so choose $K \ge 2$.